# "node/add" in search box

Tags: bug, search, meta

Sometimes lately, when I visit the MSE homepage (by typing the URL into my browser), "node/add" is pre-filled in to the search box atop the page. (If I click that box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I actually get a search for that string.) What gives?

I'm using Firefox 30.0 under Windows 7.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Probably some plugin/add-on you installed that mess things up.

Comment: It *has* been noticed intermittently, and I know the core Q&A devs are aware of it. It's mysterious and elusive though, and never reproducible at will. There's no clear reason why it should appear at all, other than those bones they found while building the new data center.

Comment: @Alex time to [call the ghostbusters](http://xenafan.com/movies/ghostbusters/555.jpg)?